# How to reformulate an excel sheet properly?

Tags: excel

I need to turn this excel sheet (one number per cell):

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
--------------------------------
1 | 1   2   3   4   5   6   7
2 | 8   9   10  11  12  13  14
3 | 15  16  17  18  19  20  21
```

into this (with all spaces between numbers, each row in one cell):

```
    A
------------
  | 1
1 | 2
  | 3 4 5
  | 6 7
—-line break—-
  | 8
2 | 9
  | 10 11 12
  | 13 14
—-line break—-
  | 15 
3 | 16
  | 17 18 19
  | 20 21
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest starting by recording a macro with relative references.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I found a formula that worked and posted it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a little playing around, I finally found a formula that worked for the above. The CHAR(10)s are the line breaks.

```
=(TRANSPOSE(A1)&CHAR(10)&TRANSPOSE(B1)&CHAR(10)&CONCATENATE(C1," ",D1," ",E1)&CHAR(10)&CONCATENATE(F1," ",G1)&CHAR(10))
```